# WPF UserControl in Listbox, Binding ICommand to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Ive build a UserControl with some Fields, and a delete button.
this Usercontrol i want to use in the DataTemplate of the Listbox.

Window.xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <WrapPanel>
          <my:User x:Name="user1" />
       </WrapPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In the ViewModel of the Window containing the Listbox Ive created an ICommand for the DeleteButton of the Usercontrol.

UserControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Name="ucUsers" .....>      
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastSeen}"  Width="140"/>
    <Button Content="Delete" 
            IsEnabled="{Binding CanUserDelete}" 
            Command="{Binding ElementName=ucUsers, Path=DataContext.DeleteCurrentUser}">
    </Button>
```

Why can I not reach the DeleteCurrentUser of the ViewModel?

Paul

Comment: why you need command if you have your del buton in UserControl.Just use button click event of the del.What you want to do on del click?

Comment: Try `Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCurrentUser, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button Content="Delete" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding CanUserDelete}" 
        Command="{Binding  Path=DataContext.DeleteCurrentUser, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
```

Comment: Just a minor Detail, had to remove "ElementName=ucUsers,"

Comment: yes It shouldnt be there . I just Copied and pasted your code and edited it .Thanks